# Is there a shortcut or extension to preview CSS property values and select one of them in VSCode?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Problem case explained:
I am coding my HTML/CSS and I apply a wrong CSS property value. What I do now is that I have to remove all the line and start typing the property name again to be able to get autocomplete suggestions to choose another value. What I want: be able to place cursor on top of wrong value and run a shortcut that shows me other values to choose from.

This behavior can be seen, for instance, in Android Studio XML properties. When you place the cursor on top of a wrong value you can press Control + Space and choose another value.

Just like you already can place the cursor on top of a color in VSC an get a color picker to choose another color, how can we do this with property values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on Windows and **Ctrl + Space** works for me.
**NOTE:** When you have selected the incorrect value (if you have any), make sure that your cursor blinks at the start of the value and not the end of the value. Otherwise, it shows No suggestions box.
i.e. to select a value,

- Place cursor at the end of the value
- Hold **Ctrl + Shift + Left Arrow Key** to select
- Then, hit **Ctrl + Space**

This will show a list of valid values for the specific property

**P.S.** VS Code Installed Version: 1.42.1

Comment: Thank you @mhsarosh . This was a silly problem. Please edit your answer and change "Place cursor at the end of the value" for "Place cursor at the beginning of the value" which is what works.